# SimpleScreenRecorder does not work with wayland

Tags: xorg, compatibility, wayland

I have upgrade from ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, but now i can not use simplescreenrecorder. I have found a way around it: *Use Xorg!* but my experience is that wayland is faster. So does anyone know how i can use simplescreenrecorder in wayland?

It does not matter if i use sudo or not. It just does not work!
I do not want an alternative, just SimpleScreenRecorder.

Comment: Maybe it's not possible. However, there are some recorders that support Wayland, eg. https://github.com/foss-project/green-recorder

Comment: @dobey `simplescreenrecorder` doesn't need to be started as root, does it? How is it a duplicate of that question?

Comment: @pomsky They are all the same issue of "Wayland is more secure, why can't I do this thing I could do under Xorg" even if there are different ways to subvert that security and "work around" the issues. Sorry if I selected the wrong question there, if there are other correct ones to be duplicate of, but search on here is quite horrible and doesn't always give the right results.

Comment: Most likely you can't use SimpleScreenRecorder in a Wayland session for now. You'll have to ask the developers of the app to add support for Wayland.

Comment: just use Kooha it runs fine on wayland ...  `flatpak install flathub io.github.seadve.Kooha`